# Import and export classes from other files

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'll create a PowerShell script and I'll to load some code from other files to reuse it. But when I import a file, I've this error:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Car]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At C:\Repo-path\test.ps1:4 char:13
+ [Car]$car = New-Object Car;
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Here is my `car.psm1` file:

```bsh
New-Module -Script {
    class Car {
        [String]$vin;
        [String]$model;
    }
}
```

Here is how I call the code:

```bsh
Import-Module -Force "C:\Repo-path\car.psm1" ;
[Car]$car = New-Object Car;
```

How could I do this?

I've also tried other ways to do the same but nothing is working.

Comment: You can also place the relative path to the file containing the class definition into the ScriptsToProcess member of the module manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Import-Module` does not load class definitions.

You'll need to use the `using module` statement at the head of your script:

```
using module C:\Repo-path\car.psm1

$car = [Car]::new()
```

---

I suggest creating modules somewhere in your `$Env:PSModulePath` so you don't need to fully-qualify the path in the import statement:

```
$path = "$HOME\WindowsPowerShell\car\1.0"
[void](mkdir $path -Force)
'class Car { [string] $Vin; [string] $Model }' | Out-File -FilePath "$path\car.psm1"
New-ModuleManifest -Path "$path\car.psd1" -RootModule "$path\car.psm1" -ModuleVersion '1.0'
```

In use:

```
using module car
```

---

#### [`about_Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-5.1)

#### [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-5.1)